# Recursive algorithm to replace every instance of a single given integer in an integer list

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

Develop a recursive algorithm to replace every instance of a single
given integer in an integer list. For example, given the inputs [1,
2, 1, 3], 1, and 39, the algorithm returns [39, 2, 39, 3].

I know how to solve for the problem if I add an extra argument that keeps count of the current index in the array but is it possible to solve using only the 3 arguments mentioned above? I am most comfortable with a psuedocode, javacsript, or java answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really no point in writing this recursively, other than as an academic exercise. Recursion can be useful to make algorithms more understandable, but in this case it's just a poor replacement for a regular old loop. Anyway, if you insist:

```
function replace(arr, x, y) {
  if (!arr.length) return [];
  var val = arr[0];
  if (val === x) val = y;
  return [val] . concat(replace(arr.slice(1), x, y));
}
```

A bit cuter in ES6:

```
function replace([head, ...tail], x, y) {
  return head === undefined ? [] : [head === x ? y : head, ...replace(tail, x, y)];
}
```

If you don't mind an internal function:

```
function replace(arr, x, y) {
  return function _replace([head, ...tail]) {
    return head === undefined ? [] : [head === x ? y : head, ..._replace(tail)];
  }(arr);
}
```

Comment: It is for an academic exercise.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recursive but a map (javascript) would do the trick:

```
myArray.map(function(d){ return d == 1 ? 39 : d})
```

Comment: I'm looking for recursion

Comment: @DanielKobe - It does meet your requirement of solving the problem using only the three inputs.  So you specifically want to apply the same function, element by element, instead of applying the same function to every element in the list at once?

Comment: I want a recursive algorithm as mentioned in the title.